# Open external links in the browser with android webview

Tags: android, browser, webview, hyperlink, external

I have this code, but not because it works, it keeps opening in webview and what I want is that the links do not belong to my website open in your default browser. Any idea? thanks

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              if(url.contains("message2space.es.vu")){
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }else{
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The problem is you need to send an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to the default web browser to open the link. What you are doing is just calling a different method in your Webview to handle the link. Whenever you want another app to handle something you need to use Intents. Try this code instead.

```java
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    final String url = request.getUrl().toString();
    if (url.contains("message2space.es.vu")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can we have long click listener on webview links?

Comment: Now i ve done this. However the app crashes because some ActivityNotFoundException.

Comment: @superUser You should open up your own question.

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil You should open up your own question.

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is deprecated.

Answer (score 32):

Since API level 24 `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` is deprecated.

Up to date solution:

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: great, this works like charm. This is really simple since it doesn't involve overwriting `WebView`. Maybe @Jaumesv can make it the new excepted answer to pin it clearly to the top...

Comment: Request.getUrl() has min SDK 21 requirements.

Answer (score 11):

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()   {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                if((String.valueOf(request.getUrl())).contains("paramedya.com.tr")) {
                    view.loadUrl(String.valueOf(request.getUrl()));
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.getUrl());
                    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is very sweet and short solution

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    context.startActivity(i);
    return true;
}
```