# How to open a URL natively in an app without using webview

Tags: android

Is there a way to open a URL in an application without using webview? Right now I'm opening a URL in webview using the code below:

```
startWebView("https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" +mGPS.getLatitude() + "," +mGPS.getLongitude() + "&daddr= 28.878444,77.133497&spn=1&t=m");

private void startWebView(String url) {

     //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
     //When opening a url or click on link

     wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {      
         //ProgressDialog progressDialog;

         //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {              
             view.loadUrl(url);

             return true;
         }

         //Show loader on url load
         public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) {

         }
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

         }

     }); 

     wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

     wv.loadUrl(url);
 }
```

Comment: where do you want the url to open ? in another browser or inside your application ?

Comment: in my application @Shivam Verma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a url inside your application you'll have to use a WebView.

Comment: and if i want to open it in other browser then have to use intent right..??
is there any way to use both webview as well as intent in my app??

Comment: How do you want to use both ? Can you give me a use case ?

Comment: in this link the use both webview and intent too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994750/open-external-links-in-the-browser-with-android-webview

Comment: Yes. this makes sure that links of only a particular websites opens in your webview. The rest of the links open in the browser.