# How to only allow links in a webView to be opened by other applications?

Tags: java, android, webview

Making an Android app that loads a url in a webView but the webpage contains links to images and videos that i do not want opened within the webview, If the user clicks on a link that doesn't load one of the whitelisted links then i want it to prompt the user to open the link in the android web browser or google chrome.

So far i have this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String url = "http://myurlhere.com";
    WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl(url);
    String currentUrl = view.getUrl();
    if (currentUrl != url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    }

}
```

But this still allows links to be opened in the webView.

Comment: Have you tried view.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(false); ?

Comment: Gave it a try but it's still loading links in the webview.

Comment: What kind of links are we talking about? Because with that code all the hyperlinks will be open outside of the webview

Comment: Basically links to imgur and other websites, It blocks nothing, Every link i click opens within the webview. :(

Comment: Add the setAllowContentAccess(false) after you finish loading the first page. If you add it before it will open the browser

Comment: Added after view.getUrl(url); still loads links within the webview.

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994750/open-external-links-in-the-browser-with-android-webview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60987/discussion-between-skilo-skilo-and-pedro-oliveira).