# Android Webview - How I can open external links in default browser?

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to make a webview application but I'm not good about it.

Just I wanna do that: I have a website and I wanna open external links in default browser like a target _blank.

My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
NavigationView navigation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
    initInstances();
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.domain.com/myprofile/");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

private void initInstances() {
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(MainActivity.this, drawerLayout, R.string.hello_world, R.string.hello_world);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    String menu1 = "https://mywebsite.domain.com/myprofile/";
    String menu2 = "https://mywebsite.domain.com/exit";
    String menu3 = "https://mywebsite.domain.com/discover/";
    String menu4 = "https://mywebsite.domain.com/settings/";
    String menu5 = "https://mywebsite.domain.com/language";
    String menu6 = "https://mywebsite.domain.com/vipmembership";

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            int id = menuItem.getItemId();
            WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            switch (id) {
                case R.id.navigation_item_1:
                    myWebView.loadUrl(this.menu1);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_item_2:
                    myWebView.loadUrl(this.menu2);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_item_3:
                    myWebView.loadUrl(this.menu3);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_item_4:
                    myWebView.loadUrl(this.menu4);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_item_5:
                    myWebView.loadUrl(this.menu5);
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_item_6:
                    myWebView.loadUrl(this.menu6);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });


}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;

    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

I tired so many code about it but it's didn't work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994750/open-external-links-in-the-browser-with-android-webview

Comment: I tired this but doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to send an Intent to to the default web browser, in order to open the link in the browser, so maybe something like this:

Create a class that extends WebViewClient, in this way:

```
private class MyCustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains("https://mywebsite.domain.com")) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i); 
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In your MainActivity, in the onCreate method, set the MyCustomWebViewClient **before the call to loadUrl method**, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    NavigationView navigation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
        initInstances();
       WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
       myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyCustomWebViewClient());
       myWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.domain.com/myprofile/");
    }

    // the rest of your code
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the best answer, please

Comment: Thanks a lot when I modified your code, it's worked! :)

Comment: Note that `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, String)` is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38484061/2750743) since sdk v24 - you should instead implement the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest)` if you target later devices or both.