# how to open external links in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I've created my simple browser app, and when i click on a link for example in whatsapp, android asks what browser should open that, and I select my browser but it doesn't open that link, instead just goes to homescreen. what should I do?

I have added this in manifest:

```
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <data android:scheme="http" />
   <data android:scheme="https" />
```

And I guess I need to add this code:
 `Uri url = getIntent().getData();
webview1.loadUrl(url.toString());`

but I don't know where to paste it, I tried it onCreate but failed.

Comment: Please paste few more codes. or explain more about what you would like to achieve.

Comment: Yes. Where is this about? And i do not see external links to begin with.

Comment: well, i am trying to create my simple browser app, and when i click on a link for example in whatsapp, android asks what browser should open that, and I select my browser but it doesn't open that link, instead just goes to homescreen. what should I do

Comment: @loddard Please add this additional information to your question.

Comment: @chrisis done. do you know the answer?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html#adding-filters

Did you try adding ACTION_VIEW to intent-filter?

Comment: no i didn't, let me try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the url from which you get the intent in OnResume() method. 
Please have a look at the code below.

```
private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webView = findViewById(R.id.external_url_content);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Uri url = getIntent().getData();
    if (url != null) {
        Log.d("TAG", "URL Foud");
        Log.d("TAG", "Url is :" + url);
        webView.loadUrl(url.toString());
    }
}
```

Also the intent-filters in manifest are as follows

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     </intent-filter>

     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
     </intent-filter>

     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
         <data android:scheme="http"/>
         <data android:scheme="https"/>
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can find more about Lifecycle Activity over [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)

Comment: now it only opens and shows url, even when i click on it, doesn't load anything

Comment: I think you have forgotten to add 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in you manifest.  Please have look at this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637654/android-webview-gives-neterr-cache-miss-message) for more info.

Comment: done, last question: is there a method other than OnResume() ? 'cause every time i return to the app's mainpage it reloads that link.

Comment: Please have a look at this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-android-activity-state-using-save-instance-state) for more info.If you are still unable to understand please raise another question as adding code in comments is not formatted and also difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

use WebView  In your layout

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/external_url_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your activity

```
WebView browser;
```

You can use this inside onCreate or functions  based on your needs

```
browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.external_url_content);
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String url_path="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48473930/how-to-open-external-links-in-webviewsid"
browser.loadUrl(url_path);
```

Comment: i need to use getIntend, but don't know how, properly

Comment: check this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17994750/open-external-links-in-the-browser-with-android-webview